# Creating a Line Graph to Display Total Pounds of each Type in a Specific Year

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a line graph that shows how many pounds each milk type sold in 2017. It comes from this dataset https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2019/2019-01-29/fluid_milk_sales.csv

This is what I have but I get a message asking if I need to adjust the group aesthetic. Not sure what I am doing wrong so I would love some assistance.

```
options(scipen = 999)

fluid_milk_sales %>%
  filter(year == 2017) %>%
  select(milk_type, pounds) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = milk_type, y = pounds)) +
  geom_line()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error your x-variable is a category and you can't join them into a line. I guess you would need a bar plot (I flip the plot so that the types can be read, you can remove coord_flip() if you don't need that) :

```
fluid_milk_sales %>%
filter(year == 2017) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = reorder(milk_type,pounds), y = pounds)) +
geom_col() + xlab("milk_type") + coord_flip()
```

[image]

Or if you want like a lollipop plot, it goes like:

```
fluid_milk_sales %>%
filter(year == 2017) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = reorder(milk_type,pounds), y = pounds)) +
geom_point() +
geom_segment(aes(xend = milk_type, yend = 0)) + 
coord_flip() + xlab("milk_type")
```

[image]

If you really want to force a line, which I think doesn't make sense (note I reorder with the negative to start with the highest):

```
fluid_milk_sales %>%
filter(year == 2017) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = reorder(milk_type,-pounds), y = pounds,group=1)) +
geom_line() + xlab("milk_type")
```

[image]

Comment: I see what you are saying, so a line graph wouldn't work? Also, how can I fix the bar chart to go in order from largest to least?

Comment: well.. you can but it might not make sense.. i can edit my answer